# magento Manage Products* logs me out

Tags: magento

Firstly let me say that I haven't changed anything on our magento installation.

This problem occured 1-2 weeks ago after updating stock products. After that an asterisk mark appeared next to Manage Products link.

When I click the Catalog -> Manage Products link it goes to /index.php/enhancedgrid/catalog_product/

I've searched all over the net but couldn't find the reason.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a 3rd party extension causing this. I see that they are actually quite a few like this. Ex: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html.

You can tell by the controller name `enhancedgrid` in the url you listed which is not a core controller for magento.

I would look for this particular extension and disable it completely in the proper xml file located in your app/etc/modules folder (or uninstall it). Then your store should behave normally again.